# How can I send jsonb[]?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one SQL function

```
FUNCTION create_user_events(_auid uuid, _name text[], _ts int[], _params jsonb[], _id int[])
```

And I am tryig to use it with following parameters:

```
SELECT create_user_events('db74c66d','{scr_home}','{1}','{{"key":"value"}::jsonb}','{123}');
```

And logout is :
ОШИБКА:  ошибочный литерал массива: "{{"key": "value"}::jsonb}"
How can I fix it?
Thank you for your time.

many variants with qoutes and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `array[]` notation:

```
create_user_events('db74c66d',
                   '{scr_home}',
                   '{1}',
                   array['{"key":"value"}']::jsonb[],
                   '{123}');
```

Alternatively you can just cast the first array element to jsonb:
 `array['{"key":"value"}'::jsonb, '{"key2":"value2"}']`

I prefer that in general over the "string syntax" for arrays:

```
create_user_events('db74c66d', 
                   array['scr_home'],
                   array[1],
                   array['{"key":"value"}']::jsonb[],
                   array[123]);
```

---

This will however result in "*invalid input syntax for type uuid: "db74c66d""* - but I assume that `db74c66d` is just a placeholder for a valid UUID.